# understanding ruby ranges

Tags: ruby, range

Iam trying to learn ruby now.. And I have doubts in ranges.
Help me in understanding ruby ranges. Also please refer some array methods that are most commonly used.

```
0..3
0...3
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(0..3).to_a=>[0,1,2,3]
(0...3).to_a=>[0,1,2]
```

First will include the last element and second will exclude the last element..

Learn rubydoc for all references in ruby

Visit http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html for array..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The two-dot form creates an inclusive range, while the three-dot form creates a range that excludes the specified high value.

```
(1..5)        #==> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ***INCLUSIVE
(1...5)       #==> 1, 2, 3, 4
```

so,

```
(1..5)==(1...5)  #==> false
```

Example of strings are more interesting:

```
('a'..'d')    #==> 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ***INCLUSIVE
('bar'..'bat')#==> "bar", "bas", "bat" ***INCLUSIVE
```

Another way of representing inclusive range is `Range.new(0,2)`

```
(0..5) == Range.new(0,5)    #=> true
```

For more information you may like to learn more about range from:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html